# purpose of TCP connection teardown

Tags: networking, tcp

TCP is a connection oriented protocol and by connection oriented what we really mean is the virtual connection.Then why do we need to terminate the connection on completion of the data exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a byte stream and the peers need to know when the byte stream ends. This is what TCP `FIN` segments are for - to tell the peer that it has received all data in the stream and that no more data will follow.

Comment: I think a slightly better way of phrasing it is, "I'm done talking, but I will still listen to anything you have to say."